# How to implement 0Auth2 without browser by using google-api-java-client

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I want to implement OAuth2 via google-api-java-client in a command line application running in a server, and there is no browser to get callback.

Does java client has something like --non-local-browser option in python client?

Or can java http client create credentials without browser callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple, just copy the url to user consent page, and grant the access of the api. After browser redirect to a new url with auth code, just copy this url and go to your server to pass this code to your program by executing cmd

`curl <url>`

you will make it.